# Pagination on category.php and tag.php not working

Tags: categories, wp-query, loop, query-posts, pagination

i'm using a query-loop on my template pages like this:

```
<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$wp_query = new WP_Query();
$wp_query->query('posts_per_page='.get_option('posts_per_page').'&paged=' . $paged);
global $wp_query;
    query_posts(array_merge($wp_query->query, array(
        'paged'          => get_query_var('paged'),
        'posts_per_page' => 2
    )));
?>
<?php if ($wp_query->have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="portfolioitem">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'portfolioteaser' ); ?>
                <div class="mask">
                    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
         <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

the pagination works fine with this except on the category.php or tag.php. The first page is showing correctly but for example if i click on "category/categoryname/page/2" it shows no content anymore an dthe pagination disappears...

i know it must be something wrong with the query loop...

help would be nice!
thanks alot,
Jochen

Comment: Why are you calling `query_posts()`? That's your problem. The fix is to get rid of `query_posts()`.

Comment: could you give me an example how to change my loop?

Comment: You don't need to change your loop. You just need to filter the `$query` properly. If you need/want to do more than just change `posts_per_page`, please update your question to indicate your needed changes.

Comment: Also, for future reference, please be sure to [search for related posts](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=custom+loop+pagination) before asking new questions. Questions about issues with pagination for custom loops are fairly common here, and is probably the reason for the downvote on your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you merely want to modify `posts_per_page` for tag and category archive index pages, don't use `query_posts()`; instead, filter the `$query` via `pre_get_posts`:

```
function wpse87489_filter_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
    if ( ( is_category() || is_tag() ) && $query->is_main_query ) {
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', '2' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse87489_filter_pre_get_posts' );
```

Comment: thanks for your quick answer... do i have to add this to my functions.php? and how do i set up my loop? could you give me an example how to change it? thanks alot...

Comment: Add filters/hooks can callbacks to `functions.php`. Use the normal loop, with no calls to `query_posts()` or `new WP_Query()`. Just call `if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();`

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following code:

```
$arg = array (
    'posts_per_page' => get_option('posts_per_page'), 
    'paged' => ( get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1 ) 
);
$wp_query = new WP_Query($arg);
if ($wp_query->have_posts()) :
    while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();
        // do something
    endwhile;
endif;
```